# Using LIKE and IN in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I need to do multiple LIKEs .

I have the following code

```
select * from product where product_code LIKE IN ('MS%','TS%')
```

However I am getting the following error

> > ORA-00936: missing expression
> > 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Am I using the correct syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in Oracle to use `LIKE` and `IN` together.

You must have to write Multiple `LIKE` and use `OR` as follows:

```
select * from product 
where (product_code LIKE 'MS%' 
   OR product_code LIKE 'TS%');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `OR`:

```
select * 
from product
where product_code like 'MS%' or
      product_code like 'TS%';
```

Or you can use regular expressions:

```
where regexp_like(product_code, '^(MS|TS)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use union

`select *  from product where product_code like 'MS%'  Union all select * from product  where product_code like 'TS%';`